# I'm trying to do a sudo apt-get upgrade, but there are some packages that are no longer required. Should I remove them?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, xubuntu, package-management

I'm trying to upgrade my packages and there were some packages that were automatically installed and are no longer required. What should I do? I'm asked to use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them, but are they important? Will removing them break something on my system?

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
    linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man apt-get`:

```
autoremove
           autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages
           and are now no longer needed.
```

So, Don't worry, It is safe to auto-remove packages by following command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```